How is $P(\frac{X}{Y} \leq t) = P(\frac{X}{\lvert Y\rvert} \leq t)$ if X and Y are standard normal?
Let X, Y ~ N(0, 1) and are iid. How can we assume that $P(\frac{X}{Y} \leq t) = P(\frac{X}{\lvert Y\rvert} \leq t)$ ? Wouldn't $\lvert Y\rvert$ be a folded normal distribution? I've seen the term symmetry thrown around, which doesn't help me wrap my head around it, since from my point of view, we're changing the distribution of Y on the RHS.

Think about the probability of $X/Y$ being less than zero. This happens if $X<0$ or $Y<0$ (but not simultaneously). Which means half of the times, i.e. p=0.5. Now, consider the latter case. The ratio is negative iff $X<0$, regardless of $Y$. Again, half of the times.

Extra insight: notice that $Y/X$ is the tangent of an angle uniform in $[0,2\pi)$, since it follows a Cauchy distribution. But one can make all possible values of $\tan \Theta$ just using half of the angles (ie [0, \pi))

This is totally wrong. $Y=-X, t=-1$ gives  a counter-example. If $X$ and $Y$ are supposed  to be independent, it is very very important to state it.

@geetha290krm you're right, in this case, X and Y are iid. Added context.

This is true for any i.i.d. symmetric random continuous variables, not just i.i.d. normal random variables.
$P(\frac X {|Y|} \le t)=P(X \le t|Y|)=P(Y>0, X \le tY)+P(Y<0, X\le -tY)$. Now use the fact that $(X,Y)$ and $(X,-Y)$ have the same joint distribution. So we can write $P(Y<0, X\le -tY)$ as $P(-Y<0, X \le -t(-Y))$ or $P( Y>0, X\le tY)$. Thus, $P(\frac X {|Y|} \le t)=P(Y>0, X \le tY)+P(Y>0, X\le tY)=2P(Y>0, X \le tY)$. Now $P(\frac XY \le t)=P(Y>0, X\le tY)+P(Y <0, X\ge tY)$. To finish the proof note that $P(Y <0, X\ge tY)=P(Y>0, X \le tY)$: This follows from the fact that $(X,Y)$ has the same distribution as $(-X,-Y)$.

Actually, $X$ need not have a symmetric distribution and $X$ and $Y$ need have the same distribution. Symmetry of $Y$ and independence of $X$ and $Y$ is enough.
